# Cannot change app theme even using GTK_THEME environnement variable

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

I am using a software called Logisim on my Ubuntu machine with a dark theme installed.
I have some visual bugs with the app and I would like to use a light theme for it.

I have already tried some solutions found on the internet but none are working for me. Here is what I tried :

- Using the GTK_THEME env variable (But it worked for apps like the gnome-calculator):

```
GTK_THEME=Yaru java -jar logisim
```

- Unquoting the line about openjdk LookAndFeel in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/swing.properties`:

```
# uncomment to set the default look and feel to GTK
swing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try is applicable for applications build using the GTK3 toolkit. That includes all programs that come with the Gnome Desktop. Other applications may use different toolkits, e.g. the QT widget toolkit is dominantly used on the Plasma desktop. Changing themes works differently for different toolkits. This is why you may not be able to change the theme of your app even using `GTK_THEME` environnement variable.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. Do you think there is anyway I can change the theme for this app specifically ? No worries if you do not !